# How to report all event payments

Tags: civireport

The CiviReport's Event Income Report (Detailed) does not show each payment. How can I show (and hopefully total) all the payments registered in the system in one report?

Comment: Am I missing something, or did my install become broken - or does the Event Income Report (Summary) look exactly the same as (Detailed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at whether [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) extension that was built by Fuzion has what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick at http://<mysite>/civicrm/report/price/lineitemparticipant.
Also - this is best installed from within CiviCRM (Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Manage Extensions)

Comment: Glad to hear it.